# Перемещение к метке по клику

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Есть карта яндекса, как можно по клику на кнопку например, вызвать событие на карте и переместиться в указанную метку на карте яндекса ?
P.S кнопка должна находиться отдельно от карты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё намного проще оказалось, вот пример кода - https://codepen.io/kah3vich/pen/mdXNYXN

```
<div class="map" id="map" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>

<button data-objectid="1">Point 1</button>
<button data-objectid="2">Point 2</button>
<button data-objectid="3">Point 3</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  goToPoint(this.dataset.idPoint);
});

/**
 * Функция центрирования карты относительно определённой метки
 *
 * param (int) idPoint - параметр, содержащий в себе идентификатор метки, который был использован при её добавлении на менеджер объектов вашей карты
 * newMap - объект вашей карты
 * setCenter - метод, устанавливайщий центр и коэффициент масштабирования карты
 * objectManager - тот самый менеджер объектов карты, при помощи которого вы добавляете метки на карту
 * objects - свойство объекта objectManager, хранящее в себе объекты карты
 * getById - метод у objectManager, который позволяет получить объект на карте через его идентификатор (в данном случае тот идентификатор, что указывали при добавлении на карту)
 * ну далее уже сами узнаете, если вдруг заинтересует
 */

function goToPoint(idPoint) {
  newMap.setCenter(objectManager.objects.getById(idPoint).geometry.coordinates, 18, {checkZoomRange: true});
}
```

```html
<button data-id-point = "<здесь_идентификатор_вашей_метки>">Кнопка</button>
```

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html - подробнее о менеджере объектов в документации к API Яндекс.Карт. Собственно, на этой же странице сможете найти примеры по добавлении меток на карту через этот объект